# General Sibling Selector That Stops Once Different Element Is Detected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

- The sibling selector `h1 + div` will select only the first div that follows and h1
- The generic sibling selector `h1 ~ div` will select all div that follow the h1 even if not directly after the h1.

My issue is I want something that sort of in-between these two options. I want to select all div following an h1 but up until the next element is not an div.

So for example, using the code below. I want a selector that effects the first 2 divs under h1 but not the div under h2. So something more like the `+` selector but that effects all elements that match until they reach one that doesn't

```
<h1>header 1</h1>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
```

I have no control over the html, or js. This needs to use pure css where all elements are on the same level.The number of content divs following a header is dynamic and could theoretically be limitless so I need a solution that can accommodate that.

This codepen ultimately shows the problem I'm trying to solve
https://codepen.io/MatteCrystal/pen/wvXaKpO

```css
h1 ~ div{
  color: red;
}

h2 ~ div{
  color: purple;
}

h3 ~ div{
  color: orange;
}

.container{
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    -- Works fine when h1-h3 are in order -- 

  <h1>H1</h1>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <h2>H2</h2>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <h3>H3</h3>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>  
</div>
<div class="container">
  -- Color should be orange, red, purple, orange -- 
  <h3>H3</h3>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <h2>H2</h2>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <h3>H3</h3>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: A good example of a seemingly simple grouping of elements that CSS can't target. Of course, the real issue here is your constraints, but the ability to limit the subsequent-sibling selector would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

If you knew there would never be more than some maximum number of divs immediately following the h1 or h2, you could just write a series of adjacent sibling rules to cover it.

(I don't like it either, but offhand I can't think of another way to do what you're trying to do within your constraints.)

```css
h1 ~ div {
  background: tomato;
}

h2 + div,
h2 + div + div,
h2 + div + div + div
{
  background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<h1>header 1</h1>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<div>content</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me. The number of content divs is dynamic and could theoretically be limitless.